# Ubuntu insserv rejected the script header

Tags: installation, init.d, uninstall

I m constantly getting this error while I m trying to install or purge any packages -

```
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

The full log is like -

```
Removing clamav-freshclam (0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for clamav-freshclam (0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99selinux' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'selinux' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service selinux and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service selinux at depth 2
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service selinux and rc.local if started
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package clamav-freshclam (--purge):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
clamav-daemon
 clamav-freshclam
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the file **selinux** located at **/etc/init.d** and no problems thereafter.

It was showing in the errors as in the question -

```
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
```